# Sum under two conditions

Tags: google-sheets, sum, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, google-sheets-query

Suppose the two following columns:

```
Close 1   Close 2
$4.28       $4.90
$37.26      $33.87
$5.34       $5.16
$887.06     $734.70
$2.68       $2.55
$14.57      $13.51
$16.76      $10.82
$1.60       $1.18
$5.15       $4.09
```

This is part of my database. Suppose **Close 1** is the price close in January 1st and **Close 2** is the close price in January 2nd. Each line in the above table is a different stock. I know how to sum up `(Close 2 - Close 1)/Close 1` for each row with

```
=SUM(ARRAYFORMULA(Database!$N$2:$N$51-Database!$L$2:$L$51)/Database!$L$2:$L$51))
```

I want to sum now only under certain conditions. I would like to make two sums where the first one will only consider the row where `(Close 2 - Close 1)/Close 1` is less than 0 and the second one where `(Close 2 - Close 1)/Close 1` is greater or equal to 0. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I would like to make two sums where the first one will only consider the row where (Close 2 - Close 1)/Close 1 is less than 0

negative:

```
=SUM(ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(IFERROR((A2:A-B2:B)/A2:A), 
 "where Col1 contains '-'", 0)))
```

---

> and the second one where (Close 2 - Close 1)/Close 1 is greater or equal to 0

positive:

```
=SUM(ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(IFERROR((A2:A-B2:B)/A2:A), 
 "where not Col1 contains '-'", 0)))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Not sure to understand what you suggest here. Can you develop a bit more?

Comment: Do you you have an alternative formula easier to understand? Even if it makes the formula longer

Comment: basically you are fishing for minus sign in column of values and filter them out before final sum

Comment: alternative: `=SUM(ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(IFERROR((A2:A-B2:B)/A2:A), 
 "where Col1 >0", 0)))`

Comment: You do that on a single row or on the two columns?

Comment: on two columns.

Comment: Last question : Can you explain A2:A-B2:B)/A2:A? What does it means?

Comment: it means this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RmTlW.png - first you do this then you wrap it into QUERY where you either filter >0 or <0 and then you SUM it all into one single value as you requested

Comment: I tried with =QUERY(((M61:M71-L61:L71)/L61:L71),''where Col1 >0''), but it seems to fail

Comment: can you share a copy of your sheet?

Comment: it should be: `=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY((M61:M71-L61:L71)/L61:L71, "where Col1 >0"))`